# What's the proper term for this execution time?

Tags: performance, algorithm, profiling, complexity-theory, execution-time

If you have some computation that you have to do for `N` elements against `X` elements.

For example if you have 10 points and 1M points in space where for each of these 1M points, you have to find the distance to the closest of the 10 points, and you require 10M operations, what kind of execution would that be called?

If I can do this in 1M operations, then I can say the whole operation executes in `linear time`, right? Since it scales linearly with the number of points. But if it's `N * X`, then would it be polynomial time?

Comment: You sound very confused. Talking about computational complexity *does not make sense* from a single data point (input foo takes k operations). It's always a function of the input. Also, linear complexity is (one instance of) polynomial complexity. f(x) = mx + c is a linear function, and it's a polynom of degree 1.

Comment: I am talking about a function that does this computation.

Comment: You're saying for N=10, X=10^7 the "function" (algorithm would be a less confusing term) does 10M operations. But that's just one data point, it has nothing to do with asymptotic complexity. Complexity theory tells you, for example, how the number of operations changes when you double N. It does this via *mathematical* functions that map the input (N, X) to a number of operations. Please read some of the [excellent answers on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complexity-theory?sort=votes).

Comment: Well yeah I am using those numbers to show a simple example of what I am talking about. Otherwise as I said for N, M inputs, the operations are N * M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input length is L=N+X, and your computation time is T=N*X.

T will never exceed (L/2)^2 = L^2 / 4, which is definitely polynomial.